# Batch check if a variable is negative

Tags: variables, if-statement, batch-file, set, false-positive

i have a little problem in batch and i don't find a way to solve it !
I'm working on a point system and just need a string that checks if a variable is negative.
It would be something like this :

```
set /p points=10
set /p price=15
set /a result=%points%-%price%
if result < 0 ( goto error ) else ( goto done)

:error
echo You have not enough Points !

:done
echo Transaction Successfully Finished !
```

The point is, i want to redirect the user to a different label depending on the fact that the variable that define the money (or something like that) is positive or negative.

EDIT : 4 years later, thanks for having helped a poor script kiddo, i'm studying IT now :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm a bit of a batch file noob (but an aspiring enthusiast!) so please excuse me if my answer isn't helpful lol.

By typing `if /?` at the command line you'll see these comparison operators:

> ```
> EQU - equal
> NEQ - not equal
> LSS - less than
> LEQ - less than or equal
> GTR - greater than
> GEQ - greater than or equal
> ```

In this case I would use this syntax:

```
if result LSS 0 (goto :error) else (goto :done)
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Hi there again!  I had a couple of free minutes and decided to expand on this and correct a few errors.  This file is tested and seems to work.  If there are any errors please let me know.

http://pastebin.com/Ksv8yZ28

Answer (score 0):

```
if result LSS 0 ...
```

or GTR GEQ LEQ EQU NEQ depending on the comparison required.

Comment: I mean instead of `if result < 0 ( goto error ) else ( goto done)` try replacing it with `if result LSS 0 ( goto error ) else ( goto done)` `LSS` means LESS THAN. Use `GTR` if you want GREATER THAN, `GEQ` for GREATER THAN OR EQUAL TO, `LEQ` for LESS THAN OR EQUAL TO, `EQU` for EQUAL TO or `NEQ` for NOT EQUAL TO.